# Is there a way to tell how much of an image is already loaded?

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-events

Is there a way to know how much percentage of one image is already loaded? Kind of a `onProgress` event for the load? So if I would do something like this:

```
$('<img/>').load(function(){
    $(this).appendTo(some div);
})
.error()
.attr('src',some source);
```

I could have some progress bar indicating how much of the previous load is complete.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to detect/get this information, it just isn't exposed to JavaScript at all...only the `onload` when it's finished is fired (or `onerror`, if it fails).